# Facilities around the Loony Dook

Tags: local-customs, festivals, edinburgh

We are a group of Germans travelling to Edinburgh for New Year's. We're taking part in the [Loony Dook](https://www.edinburghshogmanay.com/whats-on/loony-dook1) and we're wondering about facilities around the event.

Our number-one question is: **where do you change afterwards?** Are there changing rooms close to the event? Do you just change on the street (or throw some warm clothes on)? Is it ok to go to the next café/pub/restaurant and use their bathroom? Are lockers provided to store your warm clothing while taking a dip in the water?

I feel like there must be hundreds of people with similar demands, so there's probably a concept, but I can't find anything about it. Has anyone of you participated before? Do you know how things are managed?

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: According to [How to….. Loony Dook](http://www.thetaylormadetravels.com/how-to-loony-dook/) You can change in local business toilets, and you'll need someone to stay with your extra clothes

Comment: "Silliness is good for the soul …"  Yeah, but I'm not going to _buy_ a ticket to be silly.  I can do it for free anywhere (and often do).  However, if the ticket price also goes to charity, go for it!!

Comment: @Midavalo post this as an answer. Get some rep. Be happy. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the blog post [How to….. Loony Dook](http://www.thetaylormadetravels.com/how-to-loony-dook/), it appears the local businesses allow you to use their toilets to change:

> Fancy dress for the main event and people go all out for it so there
>   is no need to feel embarrassed so please make an effort. You will need
>   lots of layers for beforehand as there will be lots of waiting round
>   (you can take these off as the parade starts) and a towel and some
>   clean, dry clothes for afterwards. **There will be opportunity to change
>   in local businesses toilets.**

also

> At the registration point there are a few pubs and cafes which get
>   really busy. These open their toilets up to participants and one café
>   had a stall selling hot drinks, bacon baps, soup etc to help keep you
>   warm.

The blog also mentions that in the past there have been no lockers available to store your bags/clothes, and recommends having a friend hold onto your items for you.  It also suggests you could leave your belongings on the beach, however this comes with a little risk of losing the items, so don't take valuables.

> In 2016 there were no lockers available meaning participants had to
>   leave one person looking after everything or when they arrived on the
>   beach leave there stuff there. Only participants can get onto the
>   beach however there is always the risk of people picking up the wrong
>   bag at the end so many people get waterproof pouches and put their
>   phone and money in that. Try and limit your valuables you have on the
>   day.

Comment: So, after being there, there's not a lot to add to this answer. I would not recommend to throw your stuff somewhere at the beach because it's really crowded and there isn't really an empty spot to leave your bags. Have someone wait with your clothes at the end of the parade and try to change in local businesses. I had a great time :)